# tensorflow.map hangs randomly when using for num_parallel_calls a value > 1, using wsl2 with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, tensorflow, keras, python-multiprocessing, wsl-2

I am using tensorflow and keras on wsl for training neural networks but unfortunately i can't get the input pipeline to work reliably. Below is a minimal example of the code which causes the console to freeze at a random step and the CPU-usage to drop to a minimal level while the RAM is still occupied. After everything is frozen, wsl is unresponsive and has to be restarted.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def parse_function(filename):
    return tf.io.read_file(filename)

filenames = []
for i in range (100000):
    filenames.append("/D/test.png")

dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames))
dataset_train = dataset_train.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls =  16)
dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(50)

for epoch in range(1000):
    for step, (x_batch_train) in enumerate(dataset_train):
        print("epoch:", epoch, "start train step:",step)
```

- bypassing the map-function and directly loading everything into the RAM worked but unfortunately is not a solution since the whole dataset does not fit -> something might go wrong during mapping
- Setting the num_parallel_calls parameter of the map-function to 1 has not yet caused the problem even after days of testing but slows everything down way to much. Every other value causes a console-freeze at some point -> something might go wrong with multiprocessing during mapping
- forcing new processes to be spawned and not simply forked by including `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)` at the top of the code did not work